# Futon for Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, couchdb

Is Futon on the Ubuntu One Server availible? Is it possible to see/modify the CouchDB Databases on the Ubuntu One server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to see and modify the Ubuntu One CouchDB, but not via Futon. All you need to do is do OAuth-authenticated (but not HMAC-signed OAuth) REST requests to the right URL, using your Ubuntu One-specific Ubuntu SSO token.

One easy(ish) way of seeing the Ubuntu One CouchDB is using [a little tool I wrote](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chipaca/+junk/watgui/view/head:/watgui.py), which I called `watgui` because I'm really bad at names. It only does `GET` requests for now.

First, you use the tool to work out the “magic CouchDB URL”:
[image: watgui magic url thing]

Then, you *turn off HMAC signing*, and you can use the URL to get access to the databases. For example, here's me looking at my `notes` database:

[image: watgui looking at my notes couchdb]

Comment: As a data point, if you were interested in building something to help people work more easily with Ubuntu One CouchDBs, I'd love to talk to you :-)

Comment: @burli @sil oops, forgot the URL to watgui. Adding that...